# How to return json string inside a model property without being escaped for web API?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I have a API where I need to return a model with a property that carries a JSON string within itself. The JSON string inside is getting escaped when received at the client.

Actual : {\"ShowFilter\":true,\"FilterOptions\":[\"Week\",\"Month\",\"Year\"],\"DefaultFilter\":\"Week\",\"ShowLegend\":true,\"ShowVerticalAxis\":true,\"VerticalAxisInterval\":30,\"VerticalAxisIntervalType\":\"Integer\"}

Expected : {"ShowFilter":true,"FilterOptions":["Week","Month","Year"],"DefaultFilter":"Week","ShowLegend":true,"ShowVerticalAxis":true,"VerticalAxisInterval":30,"VerticalAxisIntervalType":"Integer"}

How can I avoid the property getting escaped without ignoring the serialization?

Comment: are you sure you're not just looking at it in the debugger

Comment: yes, I have the JSON as a string in the database, when it reaches the client it gets escaped.

Comment: Any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are looking at it within Visual Studio.  Start the API and when it is running, using a browser like Chrome (or a tool like Postman) to call the API.  This will show you what exactly is being delivered by the calling object.

Comment: I have the JSON as a string in the database, when it reaches the client it gets escaped. I am not debugging.

Comment: Any solutions ?